# issues with bootstrap and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to work with navbar (bootstrap) and jQuery and seem to be failing at getting it to work.
What I'm trying to do is quite simple (or so it seem). I'm trying to get my navbar fixed to the top of the page after scrolling past a particular number of pixels but can't seem to get it to work accurately.
Each time I scroll to the navbar, rather than the navbar getting fixed from that point on, all it does is cuts out the top border then fix from the top of the navbar items.
Here are my codes:

```js
function scrollFunction() {
 if (document.body.scrollTop > 70 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 70) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("nav").addClass("navbar-fixed-top")
  });
 } else {
  document.getElementsByTagName("nav").className = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./ok.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./Codepen project/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Codepen project/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./Codepen project/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="./Codepen project/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./Codepen project/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./ok.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body style="height:1000px;background-color:;" onscroll="scrollFunction">
  <div class="container" style="height:70px;">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
       <td style="padding-right:10px"><h1>Welcome to my Portfolio</h1></td>
       <td style="position:absolute;bottom:0;padding-left:10px;border-left: 1px solid black"><h3>In a bid to actualizing my dream...</h3></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="position:relative;height:70px;">
     <div id="contact" style="position:absolute;right:0px;bottom:0">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="nav">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#myDrop'>
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="font-size:1.25em !important;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i> 'Tunde Aromire</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id='myDrop'>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"> Home</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg"> Portfolio</i></a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-lg"> Contacts </i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg"></i></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/tunde1990">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/tunde1990">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.codepen.io/toondaey">Codepen</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info fa-lg"> About</i></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </nav>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script src urls aren't proper references. Also finish your addClass line of code with a semi-colon. And why not be consistent and removeClass in the same way with jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the citation. Could you please enlighten me as to how to properly reference the script src. I would really appreciate that.

Comment: So I guess you're doing this in codepen as your src says "Codepen project" , so this is a pseudo reference? If this was an actual reference it would have to be "./codepen-project/etc". You could optionally use a CDN (content delivery network) to host them.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for that. I understand that I have to use a CDN method to reference the scripts, however, I want to complete developing the entire page before uploading the code to codepen. I'm going to change the respective references when I upload the code. But right now, I downloaded the respective libraries on my laptop in order to finish it first hence that reference pattern. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but try declaring your scrollTop function without the document.ready thing, like this:

```
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 70 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 70) {
        $("nav").addClass("navbar-fixed-top")
    } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName("nav").className = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, upon disconnection of the external screen I was using, the whole thing just refused to work completely. Rather than fixing the position, the bar just scrolls with the entire page. I don't know what happened.